# Using "will" vs "would" to express (desire/willingness) in the present

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, modal-verbs, conversation

If I'm in the present time and I'm trying to open the door using the key that doesn't want to go inside the lock. Should I say:

1- The key wouldn't go in.

2- They key won't go in.

Answer (score 0):

You would say “won’t”.

“Would” (which can also be used to refer to a future hypothetical, as I have done in the first sentence of this answer) is the past tense of “will” (which is present tense).